# wp-login.php redirects to homepage not to wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

After you log in wp-login.php wordpress it brings me to the main page, not the administrator panel. Permissions capabilities have set to `a: 1: {s: 13: "administrator"; b: 1;}`
while `user_level 10,` turn off all plugins from the database, the error still occurs, has anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are logging in as an administrator... I mean is your user role set as administrator...

Try and see if you can manually edit the user role from the phpmyadmin and set it as an administrator...

Under the general settings... Make sure you put the right email for the admin don't that you can also use it to login as the admin.

Try those and let see if it works